# Pass value with a button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have in my DB values in array.

```
"ExercisesData": [
    {
      "Id": "01",
      "Reps": "10",
      "StartDate": "2019-06-20",
      "EndDate": "2019-06-21",
      "Notes": "...."
    },
    {
      "Id": "02",
      "Reps": "1",
      "Notes": "....."
    },
    {
      "Id": "03",
      "Reps": "150",
      "Notes": "......"
    }
  ]
```

I take these values and create a button for them. Like this:

```
checkAttività (){
   //..... 
}

  render() {
    const exercises = this.state.Exercises.map(exercise => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Id: {exercise.Id}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Reps: {exercise.Reps}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Note: {exercise.Notes}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styleButton.button, styleButton.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.checkAttività(exercise.Id)}>
            <Text style={styleButton.buttonTesto}>Choose</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

In this way I create a button for every values in array. What I should do, is to create a button which allows me to pass the id value corresponding to the clicked key. In the sense:

> Id: 01
>
> Reps:
>
> Notes: ...
>
> Button1

---

> Id: 02
>
> Reps:
>
> Notes: ...
>
> Button2

If I click on the button1 I would pass the value of the Id (01). How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: the above code looks fine, do you get any errors? fyi change `this.state.Exercises` to `this.state. ExercisesData`

Comment: I would not recommend using non-ascii for names though `checkAttività`

Comment: @JuniusL. I have tried to print in the console log the id in the function checkAttività and it doesn't print nothing

Comment: you need to add paramter to your function see https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/blessed-toffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `id` parameter in `checkAttività` like:

```
checkAttività (id){
 //..... 
}
```

You already have used anonymous function, so it shoud do the trick:

```
onPress={() => this.checkAttività(exercise.Id)}
```

Also you should bind your event, eg in constructor:

```
this.checkAttività = this.checkAttività.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Just bind the event and you will be able to pass any params.

```
onPress={ this.someEvent.bind(this,exercise.Id)}

someEvent(id){
   console.log("You will get the id: ",id);
}
```

Comment: We can do it this way as well and it works perfectly fine. Binding need not to be done in constructor only.

Comment: "The bind() method creates a new function" - you shouldn't be creating a new function in every `onPress`. Whilst I know this works, you should adhere to good practices. Alternatively, use an arrow function.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, because it might be a performance issue and is not considered as a good practice.Thank you @Dan for reminding it.